# SSO for Azure B2C

Tags: azure, single-sign-on, azure-ad-b2c

Two apps in Azure B2C, sign up and in to App 1 we are prompted for MFA on both Apps, want a scenario where once I sign into App 1, no MFA for sign in to App 2 will be required. Any help please?

Comment: Do you want Single Sign In for the 2 apps (so if the user signs in into app1, it should automatically be given access, without any login, to app2), or you want two different independent logins, one with MFA for app1 and one without MFA for app2?

Answer (score 1):

Create two user policies; one for each application.

In the policy for App2, set MFA on.